# Rake not working because of config.time_zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm extremely new to rails. I'm running ruby 1.9.3 on Rails 2.3.14. Every time I try to run

```
rake db:migrate
```

I get an error saying:

```
Rake Aborted! Value assigned to config.time_zone not recognized.
Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding appropriate time zone names.
```

I looked around for a bit and figured that it can happen if your config.time_zone is uninitialized.

I checked the environment file. Turns out it is initialized to 'UTC'.

```
# config/environment.rb

Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  config.time_zone = 'UTC'
end
```

Rake still does not work. What other factors should I be considering?

Comment: I'd start with ruby 1.9.3 not playing nicely with rails 2.x. If you can, change to rails 4. Alternatively use ruby 1.8.7 for rails 2.3.x. See rvm.io for how to install multiple ruby versions.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try doing that.

Comment: Note that both Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3 are no longer maintained, and both have known security vulnerabilities, so try to upgrade to Ruby 2.2 and Rails 4.x.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I'm upgrading. Do you think there's something else I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For show time zones with specific offset run:

```
$> rake time:zones:all OFFSET=+6
   Then you can show the cmd or terminal like this 

   UTC +06:00 *
   Almaty
   Astana
   Dhaka
   Ekaterinburg
```

If you change the OFFSET=+6 then you can get many place names.

Now insert this code in your application.rb:

```
# config/application.rb

config.time_zone = 'Astana'
```

Astana you can change the name according to your area name.
It is working for me .

Thanks.